# Get fields of second category in product page

Tags: prestashop

I am very new to prestashop so this might be very easy but I don't know how to do it.
I want to display some fields of a category from a product but I am only able to display from default category, I want to display the image of the second category ( I am also displaying the main category image) right now I have this

```
<img src="{$link->getCatImageLink($category->link_rewrite, $category->id_image, 'catlogo')|escape:'html'}" alt="{$category->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"  />
<div>Region: {$category->Region} {$category->name}</div>
<div>Adresse: {$category->Adresse}</div>
<div>Site web: {$category->Site_web}</div>
```

I know I can get an array of the categories with this :

```
  {$product->getProductCategories($product->id)}
```

but I am not able to use this information to get the desired image, I've search in the forums but with no success, can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Using same function and iterating the array should do the trick eg:

$categories=$product->getProductCategories($product->id);
foreach($categories as $category)
{
getCatImageLink($category->link_rewrite, $category->id_image, 'catlogo')|escape:'html'}" alt="{$category->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"  />
}

Also there is the  $product->getProductCategoriesFull($id_product, $id_lang)  function available that returns category name and rewrite link additionaly  in order to get results for each language.